# Inject js and scss into php using webpack

Tags: javascript, php, webpack

So I'm having my webpack setup and build everything in html files with the `html-webpack-plugin`. That worked fine, but now I have to create some PHP files but I can't seem to find a single example on how to make it work.

I'm running MAMP and I'm proxying my webpack-dev-server already. This works fine and I can reach the php pages. The issue however is that Webpack doesn't inject my HTML and CSS, so all I see is a plain HTML/PHP file rendered in my browser.

That's most likely because I don't have a loader. I tried a few from but those were deprecated already.

Is there any way to still be able to serve PHP files while using webpack as the compiler? Some workaround that involves gulp or browsersync alongside webpack is fine as well.

My dev server is currently setup like this;

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/'),
    watchContentBase: true,
    inline: true,
    hot: true,
    port: 3000,
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:8888/app',
    proxy: {
        '*': 'http://localhost:8888'
    }
},
```

PHP file with the form that I'm trying to fix;

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php include 'signupForm.php' ?>
        <main>
            <section class="sz-pitchdark">
                <div class="col-6" data-push-left="off-1">
                    <form class="contact-form" autocomplete="off">
                        <input autocomplete="off" type="hidden" name="token" id="token" value="">
                        <div class="sz-select-wrapper">
                            <select class="sz-select">
                                <option>I'm interested in</option>
                                <option>An exciting new project</option>
                                <option>Partnering up</option>
                                <option>A little chit-chat</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="sz-input-wrapper">
                            <input class="sz-input" type="text" id="name"></input>
                            <label class="sz-label" for="name">
                                <span class="sz-label-text">
                                    Name
                                </span>
                            </label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="sz-input-wrapper">
                            <input class="sz-input" type="tel" id="telephone"></input>
                            <label class="sz-label" for="telephone">
                                <span class="sz-label-text">
                                    Telephone (not required)
                                </span>
                            </label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="sz-input-wrapper">
                            <input class="sz-input" type="email" id="email"></input>
                            <label class="sz-label" for="email">
                                <span class="sz-label-text">
                                    E-mail
                                </span>
                            </label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="sz-input-wrapper">
                            <textarea class="sz-input text-area" type="text" id="message"></textarea>
                            <label class="sz-label" for="message">
                                <span class="sz-label-text">
                                    You're on! Clear your heart
                                </span>
                            </label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="grid">
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <button class="sz-primary-button">
                                    Send message
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </section>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what does your PHP server actually do in your project? should it provide HTML views as well or is it just an api?

Comment: It's a HTML view on it's own. Most of the pages contain a form that I need to submit. So that's why I need the styling and js!

Comment: and you want webpack to do what? usually you use webpack / webpack-dev-server to have a small webserver on your localhost during the development. afterwards you let webpack create a bundle and this bundle should be served from your webserver

Comment: That's correct, but I'm using webpack right now to compile my scss files to a css file, to compile my js exports and imports to and livereload my localhost (dev environment). The issue now is, that when I use a PHP file, none of this is happening and the webpack proxy only renders the HTML part without any markup.

I also have a prod config that compiles everything into a dist folder which I move onto my webserver.

Comment: i still do not understand your project setup entirely - do you have an mamp running as a reverse proxy for your webpack server? if yes, what is your idea behind this?

Comment: Haha no worries, I'll try to do my best to explain it. So I have the following;

A PHP Server (MAMP), to run my PHP files which contain the forms and some HTML formatting that I need to render. Webpack itself isn't a PHP server of course. To have some livereload, and being able to use scss and js imports and exports on the PHP files and some HTML files I'm running Webpack. But if I were to run the Webpack server alone, I can't use the PHP server, and it can't open the PHP files. It would only download them, that's why it's running as a proxy.

Comment: ok it's getting a bit clearer....can you please post one of that .php files you want to get working?

Comment: Just added it! Let me know if you need anything else. I stripped it down a bit, there is some nav and footer in the php file as well. The complete script for making this form work is something that I still need to create, but that's something I would like to run through an ajax call.

Comment: this is just an HTML file with no containing PHP code. And this is also a complete HTML document (enclosed within the `<html></html>` tag). I guess what you are really searching for is a `template engine` - for me it seems that this question is much too broad - we can continue discussing in the chat for clarifying if you want to

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187768/discussion-between-messerbill-and-wouter125).